# Arbitrary user-defined constraints on database results

Tags: php, mysql, database, constraints

In a survey framework, where user input (ie "asking" survey questions, not answering them) is fairly trusted, my predecessor went with building a MySQL query pretty much straight from user-defined constraints (ie without doing much about the possibility of malicious SQL injection, since SQL injection was the intended result).

In most cases these constraints would be something like skip this question if `sex = 1` which would then translate into a query like

`SELECT IF(sex = 1) AS test FROM Survey1 WHERE user_id = 12`

In more complex cases the constraint might be
`Survey1.agreed = 1 OR (Survey2.age < 50 AND Survey2.age > 18) OR Survey3.number_of_children IN(2,3,5,7)`
 where he would have to build joins etc. to support unlimited complexity and nesting.

Obviously, there are many ways in which letting users pretty much specify the WHERE part of a query can go wrong, even if malicious users are rare.
He tried parsing these constraints himself, but with the complex cases this performed so badly, that in the end he went with the unsafe but fast approach.

What could be a safe, somewhat performant solution to this problem?

Comment: It depends on what your users are suppose to be doing. You can allow them to run any SQL with a separate MySQL user which has permissions to read only a few tables. That approach has severe limitations but it is very simple compared to parsing queries.

Comment: @Vatev Yes, that would be a good first-order safeguard. Unfortunately different MySQL users are often not permitted on shared hosters and university servers (among them my uni). This is really unfortunate and I don't know why they do that, usually they obsess about security. But one other safety issue would be if an inexperienced, but not malicious survey designer is able to add a constraint that in turn allows a malicious end user to read out other users' survey entries. A bit constructed, but possible.